# tampermonkey запуск скрипта через контекстное меню

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

Как запустить скрипт нажав правую кнопку мыши и выбрав нужный скрипт? 
Использую этот параметр:

```
@ run-at context-menu
```

и пытался использовать вот такую функцию:

```
GM_registerMenuCommand ("Запуск", start);
```

Где start - это название функции запускающей программу.

Так как же все таки запустить программу таким образом?
[image: Скриншот]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прошу прощения за мой машинно-русский перевод.

В любом случае, `@run-at context-menu` и`GM_registerMenuCommand()` специально не предназначены для совместного использования.
Первый размещает пункт контекстного меню на **каждой** странице. Второе место - меню меню *Tampermonkey* только для выбранных страниц (как определено директивами `@ match`,`@ include` и т. Д.).

Рассмотрим этот скрипт Tampermonkey (который работает только в браузерах Chrome):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         context-menu fun (забавное контекстное меню)
// @match        https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour
// @grant        GM_registerMenuCommand
// @run-at       context-menu
// ==/UserScript==
console.log ("Запуск скрипта");

GM_registerMenuCommand ("Запуск", start);

function start () {
    console.log ("Функция запуска запущена.");
}
```

Обратите внимание, что строка `@match` будет игнорироваться, поскольку используется `@run-at context-menu`.

Если вы установите этот скрипт и посетите https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour, вы увидите:

1) Во-первых, нет пункта меню Tampermonkey для этого скрипта и нет сообщений в консоли:

> [image: step 1]

2) Затем запустите скрипт из контекстного меню страницы:

> [image: step 2]

3) Затем вы увидите пункт меню Tampermonkey, который вы можете запустить:

> [image: step 3]